# Simple Robocopy Move (noob)

Tags: robocopy

I cant seem to get this Robocopy move to work.

I hit the following command and I get an invalid parameter #3. E drive is external.

C:\Users\PedroL>ROBOCOPY C:\Users\PedroL\Downloads\Directions Raws E:\Stuff /move /minage:20141021

---

ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

---

Started : Tue Oct 21 13:11:24 2014

Source - C:\Users\PedroL\Downloads\Directions\
     Dest - C:\Users\PedroL\Raws\

```
Files :
```

Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

---

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "E:\Stuff"

```
   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
```

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

Comment: You need quotes around arguments containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your path `C:\Users\PedroL\Downloads\Directions Raws` has a space in it between "Direction" and "Raws", which is making robocopy interpret it as two commands. Add quotes around it `"C:\Users\PedroL\Downloads\Directions Raws"` and ROBOCOPY will interpret it correctly.